# Reading and writing large files to and from Google Drive or Cloud Storage using Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I was wondering if Google App Engine supports reading and writing large files ( example, text files of size more than 2GB ) into and from Google Drive or Cloud Storage ?

What problems can I expect?

I'm using the Python 2,7 Google App Engine SDK by the way.

---

Updates.

I intend to read up to a million rows of data from Google's Data Store ( or maybe the new NDB ), and save the data into a text file for further processing either on Google Cloud Compute or some third party services like PiCloud.

The data is basically a network relationship and it goes like this:

```
A -> B
B -> C
A -> D
```

The above means that A is linked to B, B is linked to C and A is linked to D and so on...

As i have over a million edges, i think i might have to use the task queue or cron job to do this?

So after i processed the relationships, i'll have another text file which contains some scores between each pair of nodes, which i will than write back into the database.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does - the question is how do you intend to write the files?

You can either upload direct to Cloud Storage using either [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) or [create_upload_url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions), or you can write from your app using this [files API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/).

If you're using the file API then you need to read or write in chunks no larger than 32MB.

Comment: hello, I intend to read up to a million rows from the google data store ( or perhaps the new NDB ) and write it into a text file. I want to save this text file for further processing using Google Cloud Compute or some third party services like PiCloud.

Answer (score 1):

an API is around for app engine or I suppose you can use the REST cloud api. I just started with this  but here is the api page
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/

Comment: oh ok i see. i was not clear with my question. please see update? thanks!